# Mystery error running .NET 3.5 program on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, .net

Why can't I run this program?  I get error like:

```
Description:
  Stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: generatecodes.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 4f0b0ab4
  Problem Signature 04: GenerateCodes
  Problem Signature 05: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4f0b0ab4
  Problem Signature 07: 4
  Problem Signature 08: 10
  Problem Signature 09: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.274.10
  Locale ID:    1033
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it cannot locate a certain file. Either because the file doesn't exist or because the process does not have access to read the file or execute on the directory. Use [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to determine on what file operation the Exception is thrown

Open up Process Monitor and add a filter to sort out any events that does not have anything to do with your application, like this:

[image]

Press OK, minimize ProcMon, and open your application. When the application crashes, go back to procmon, stop the Capture, by pressing the loupe icon or CTRL+E on your keyboard. Make sure the File System Events are shown, by verifying that the file cabinet icon is pressed (on the image it is *not*):

[image]

Scroll down to the last few events you've captured and examine the stack trace of each operation by double-clicking on the event.

Comment: -Ok, I've downloaded, but I'm not sure what I"m looking for?

Comment: Updated answer, play around with ProcMon, examine the file system events and the errors it might show you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this file not found exception with the Intel RST software. See http://alasdaircs.wordpress.com/2011/08/18/intel-rst-and-net/

In short, make sure you have the .NET 3.5.1 feature installed, not just .NET 4.0.

HTH.